# android action bar sherlock. lable/text of icon disappears while animating

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-animation, rotateanimation

i am trying to show a refresh animation in my action bar sherlock.
the animation works just fine (rotating the refresh icon) and does what it is supposed to. The only problem is the text/label for the button disappears although there is enough space available. It returns as soon as the animation stops.

here are my code snippets:

anim/rotate.xml

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="360"
    android:toDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="1500"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" />
```

menu items xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >   
  <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/menu_refresh"/>

</menu>
```

layout/refresh_action.xml

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
          android:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom"
          android:title="@string/menu_refresh"
          style="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton" />
```

and the java code in my fragment

```
private Animation rotation;
private static ImageView syncView;
private static MenuItem syncItem;

private void refreshAnimation() {
    /* Attach a rotating ImageView to the refresh item as an ActionView */
     LayoutInflater lI = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
             .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     refreshView = (ImageView) lI.inflate(R.layout
             .refresh_rotate_action, null);
     rotation =  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), 
             R.anim.refresh_rotate);
     rotation.setAnimationListener(rotateListener);
     refreshView.startAnimation(rotation);
     refreshItem.setActionView(syncView);
}
```

I hope someone here has a solution for this problem because it is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a rotating loading view built into the actionbar. It looks pretty nice. See the following:

```
getSherlockActivity().setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

Comment: this is one way to solve this but it is not really what i am looking for. i really want to have this rotating refresh icon because of the style. only thing bothering me is the disappearing label :(